# Django Sentry installation step error

Tags: django, sentry

I wanted to log what happened with my Django app on my test server so I've installed Django Sentry.

I've done everything as it is in the Quickstart guide from the official documentation but when I try to initialize the web service this error appears:

```
sentry.conf.py start
Performing upgrade before service startup...
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Migrating...
Running migrations for djcelery:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for djcelery.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for django:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for django.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for django:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for django.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for sentry:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for sentry.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > crispy_forms
 > sentry.plugins.sentry_mail
 > sentry.plugins.sentry_servers
 > sentry.plugins.sentry_urls
 > sentry.plugins.sentry_user_emails
 > sentry.plugins.sentry_useragents
 > social_auth
 > south

Migrated:
 - djcelery
 - kombu.transport.django
 - raven.contrib.django
 - sentry
Running service: 'http'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/sentry", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('sentry==5.0.21', 'console_scripts', 'sentry')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/sentry/utils/runner.py", line 150, in main
    initializer=initialize_app,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/logan/runner.py", line 136, in run_app
    management.execute_from_command_line([runner_name, command] + command_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/sentry/management/commands/start.py", line 78, in handle
    service.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/sentry/services/http.py", line 46, in run
    call_command('run_gunicorn', **self.options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 134, in call_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gunicorn/management/commands/run_gunicorn.py", line 10, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.djangoapp import DjangoApplicationCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/djangoapp.py", line 9, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.base import Application
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    from gunicorn.config import Config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py", line 241
    except ImportError as e:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gunicorn requires Python 2.6 - which added the `except T as e` syntax (see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/). You'll need to switch to at least Python 2.6.

Note that in some places the documentation for gunicorn says it supports Python 2.5, but that is [no longer true](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/427).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Switching to newer version of Python is not an option since there are many apps running on it (not mine, so don't want to break them).